# ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222 when trying to run Microsoft Office Add-In Debugger

Tags: visual-studio-code, outlook, windows-10, outlook-web-addins, vscode-debugger

When attempting to run the debugger for the Microsoft Office Add-In Debugger extension for VS Code, I get this error when clicking the 'Play' button:

[image]

I have seen this question asked multiple times before [for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36783068/cannot-connect-to-the-target-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-19222), but nothing specifically for Microsoft Office Add-Ins.

I have tried:

- Restarting VS Code and restarting my machine
- Running `netstat -an | find /i "listening"` to view which ports are listening on my machine, and tried replacing port `9222` with each of these ports for the `"port"` value in launch.json
- Tried updating the port key to target port `4200`, (the port which my application is hosted on, https://localhost:4200)
- Verifying that the webRoot is the correct path.
- Removing the `port` key in launch.json entirely

For reference, I am running this web add-in in Outlook native on Windows 10 version 1903.

From what I can tell, my `launch.json` seems okay:

```
  {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch index.html",
            "type": "office-addin",
            "request": "launch",
            "file": "${workspaceRoot}/index.html",
            "browserTarget": "Edge"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch localhost with sourcemaps",
            "type": "office-addin",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost/mypage.html",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "wwwroot",
            "webviewTarget": "Edge"
        },
        {
            "type": "office-addin",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Office Add-ins",
            "port": 53483,
            "trace": "verbose",
            "url": "https://localhost:4200/index.html?_host_Info=Outlook$Win32$16.01$en-US$$$$0",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/app",
            "timeout": 45000
        }
     ]
  }
```

I've walked through the documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations) several times but no luck. Does anyone have any idea on how to get around this so that I can run the debugger for my Outlook web Add-In?

Answer (score 1):

If you worked this out, please come back here and post an explanation so you can help us, as well as us helping you.

Note: you need to tag your office-js questions with office-js (that's what the Office JS Microsoft employees listen to and reply on)

**Meanwhile - this workaround seems useful to me:**

Put this into your `taskpane.html`:

```html
<textarea id="out" rows=10 cols=46>debug info here</textarea>
```

And then instead of using `console.log()` you can use something like this:-

```js
document.getElementById("out").value += "Ready...\n";
```

Also - it looks like you can install DevTools and the old EdgeHTML engine (by installing JavascriptBrowser) as per my comments here: [Can someone from Microsoft please write a working instruction for how to debug Microsoft-365 Apps now-days (post-August-2021)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68720938/can-someone-from-microsoft-please-write-a-working-instruction-for-how-to-debug-m)